# Is the subspace $K=\{f\in L^p(\mathbb{T}): S_Nf\xrightarrow{p}f\}$ closed in $L^p(\mathbb{T})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Trying to consider a sequence $\{f_m\}$ in $K$ such that $f_m\xrightarrow{p}f$ and demonstrate that $f\in K$. If I can show that $\limsup_{N\to\infty} \lvert\lvert S_N(f-f_m)\rvert\rvert_p\to 0$ as $M\to \infty$ then I will be done via the triangle inequality. Not quite sure how to do this or if this is even true though. I suspect that it's probably not. Here $S_N$ is the $N^{th}$ Fourier partial sum by the way. Also here $1\leq p<\infty$.

Comment: IF you can prove a weak-type bound $m(|S_Nf|>\lambda)\leq \frac{c}{\lambda^q}(\|f\|_p)^q$, then things will follows from the Marcinkiewicz decomposition.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but since $K$ is convex, it suffices to show weak closure.

Comment: The idea I suggested is a classical. Here is a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970516?seq=1) that deals with this. Hopefully this will help you with your problem.

Comment: I am studying out of Duoandikoetxea's 'Fourier Analysis' and he states that the uniform boundedness principle gives the 'only if' direction in $\lvert\lvert S_Nf-f\rvert\rvert_p\to 0$ iff there exists $C_p$ independent of $N$ such that $\lvert\lvert S_Nf\rvert\rvert_p\leq C_p\lvert \lvert f\rvert\rvert_p$. I am trying to get a contradiction in the one of the uniform boundedness principle cases by restricting $L^p$ instead to the subspace $K$, which I would like to show is Banach in order to use Uniform boundedness. If I can show it is closed then it is Banach.

Comment: @MSA2016: Is $S_Nf\xrightarrow{p}f$ convergence in $L_p$? your notation is not very clear. Id so, notice that if $f\in \overline{K}$ and $f_n\in K$ is such that $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f $ in $L_p$, then each $f_n$ satisfies the condition $\|S_Nf_n\|p\leq C_p\|f_n\|$. Repeating the prof of Lemma 1.8 with $f_n$ in place of $g$ would give you the answer.

Comment: To me it seems like finding such a $C_p$ independent of the $f_n$ is equivalent to the problem. I can find a $C_p$ which depends on the $f_n$, but this is not enough to do the same technique as in the lemma. Could you give some more details?